# How to set dimensions for different Screens in Android development

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I am new to the Android development environment.
I would like to have my app designed for multiple phone screen sizes and resolutions. 
If the design for all the screens remain the same, will I be able to use one XML layout for the design with the dimensions specified in "dp" and "sp".
Will android automatically scale the dimensions and font sizes for each phones(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, xxdpi, xxxdpi) automatically? Or do I have to create separate layout files for each of them with the respective dp/sp values? 
Also, I hope if I put images for each dip in their respective folders, android would pick it up by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Create layouts for screens like this:

**res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")**

**res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size**

**res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size**

**res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation**

*res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density*

*res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density*

*res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density*

*res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density*

Comment: Hi Madi. In practice, in each of these separate layout files, what would be difference? Each will have the same xml elements with different dp/sp value for the dimensions?

Comment: Hi Habeeb! Yeah you are rigth! Each files have same xml layout name but contains different sizes